# Hikaru no Go Manga - dialogue question

Tags: katakana, idioms, manga

So this is a sentence I picked from *Hikaru no Go*, Vol. 1, that I am reading.

> どれもこれも**パツ**としないなあ

What does パツ mean in this sentence and how do you usually find those kind words? When I searched on [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/) I did not find anything.

Here is another sentence:

> バーカ 囲碁だよ 碁盤とか いう **ヤツ** だ

What does ヤツ mean in this sentence ?

> 頭 が おもて一 **やつぱ**コレはきのうの...

What does やつぱコレ mean in this sentence?

Comment: It looks like you have trouble distinguishing っ and ッ from つ and ツ...

Comment: You are totally correct and I will try to look more closely to distinguishing っ and ッ from つ and ツ.

Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be 「パ**ッ**」 with the small 「ッ」 rather than 「パ**ツ**」 with the full-size 「ツ」.

「パッとしない」 means "to not be good enough", "to not stand out", etc.

> 「どれもこれもパツとしないなあ」 means
>
> "None of these/those are good enough (for me)."
>
> or "These/Those are all mediocre."

Moving on..

「ヤツ」 here means "a/the thing".  (Full-size 「ツ」 here.)

> 「バーカ [囲碁]{いご}だよ [碁盤]{ごばん}とか いう ヤツ だ」 =
>
> "You fool, it is Go!  That is what they call a Go board! "

Lastly, it is a small 「っ」 again in 「やっぱ」.  It is not 「やつぱ」.

「やっぱ」 is a colloquial version of 「やっぱり」, which is already an informal version of 「やはり」.

All three mean "as I/you/they thought", "you see!", "after all", etc.　It is a word a native speaker uses a dozen times a day.

> 「[頭]{あたま} が おもて一 やつぱコレはきのうの...」 =
>
> "My head feels heavy.  You see, this has gotta be ~~~ from yesterday."

It is hard to translate without more context.  「おもてー」 is how 「[重]{おも}たい」 (= "heavy") is pronounced informally (mostly in Kanto).

Comment: The last sentence has a やつぱ instead of やっぱ. Might make things confusing for the OP. Tried to edit but that was the only thing wrong, so it wouldn't let me. Wah.